# challenging with signalR hub classes?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i have asp.net project . i want create chat room with signalR class. First Of all i install the Package and nugget But  i cant see the Signal hub Classes in my new item Field . there is my install message from package =>

```
                Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
                The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable.     
                 Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at  
                C:\Users\sali\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache

                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.6.4)'.
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb                                     
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (≥ 
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.0)'.
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Owin (≥ 1.0)'.
                  Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin (≥ 2.0.1)'.
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Security (≥ 2.0.1)'.
                 Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (≥ 
                  'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.0.3' already installed.
                 Prsonal already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.0.3'.
```

whats problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of VS? 2012 does not have them, and Nuget packages do not install templates, they contain just the binaries. From your log messages is clear that you cannot reach Nuget (2nd line), but it's also clear that you already have SignalR referenced. If you want to add a Hub class just add a simple class and make it derive from `Microsoft.AspNet.Signalr.Hub`, you do not need the template for that.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 . In Fact I am Creating Chat Form But I Cant . Can You Help ME ? Thank You